# How to update a table td value with the input field value?

Tags: jquery

When I click the update button, the table td values should be updated with the input field values. Here is the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/priyaa2002/PWYhD/7/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#update').click(function(){
       var txt = $(#name).val();
       $('tname').val(txt);                   
});
```

name:
                        my name

```
<div class="col2-content" id="info">
    <div class="para">
        <ol>
            <li>
                 <label for="name">name:</label>
                  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" onclick="return false;">
             </li>
         </ol>
         <div class="update">
            <button id="update" type="submit">update</button>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ahh... shouldn't it be .html? Isn't .val for inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `html()` for setting or getting `td` value and `val()` to get or set `input` value.\

```
$('#tname').html($('#name').val());
//html('somevalue') sets td's value and html() fetches it's value
//val('somevalue') sets input's value and val() fetches it's value
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/PWYhD/6/

Answer (score 4):

Your fiddle was riddled with JS errors and wrong method calls, that's why it didn't work. You should have the JS console visible at all times because it shows errors in your coding.

Anyway, I cleaned it up and it works

```
$(function() {
      $('#edit').click(function() {
           $('#info').show();
       });
        $('#update').click(function(){
           $('#tname'). html($('#name').val());
           $('#avatar').html($('#gmae-id').val());
           $('#temail').html($('#phone').val());
    });

});
```

When changing the html inside elements use the `.html()` tag and not `.val()`

**[Here's a working fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/priyaa2002/PWYhD/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

If that code is copy-pasted from your actual files, you have a small error:

```
   var val = $('#name').val();// use quotes around selector
   $('#tname'). val($('#name').attr('value'));// you forgot the hash
```

**UPDATE**

Just checked your fiddle, `val()` only works with form elements. Try using `html()` for other tags.

[Here's my example on fiddle.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Khez/MzacP/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing some single quotes in your jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $('#update').click(function(){
       var val = $('#name').val();
       $('tname').val($('#name').attr('value'));                   
});
```

That should fix it.